# Плавающее окно ответа

Tags: предложение, ответы

Когда вопрос уже имеет хотя бы один ответ, а хочется дать новый, то между блоком ввода ответа и вопросом будет находиться список уже ранее опубликованных ответов. Это довольно неудобно, т.к. иногда приходится обращаться к тексту вопроса, и приходится прокручивать страницу через имеющиеся вопросы. Было бы неплохо иметь возможность как-то перенести блок ввода ответа ближе к телу вопроса. Например, сделать окно ввода ответа плавающим.

P.S. Я не за расположение блока для ответа сразу под вопросом. А за возможность переместить его после начала редактирования туда куда хочется.

Comment: или просто поместить его сразу под вопросом? и туда же смещать окно редактирования уже существующего вопроса

Comment: @VladD в принципе не важно как, лишь бы поле ответа было рядом с вопросом в процессе написания ответа.

Comment: @VladD, не, это будет поощрять отвечать на вопрос не читая ответов и плодить дубли.

Comment: @Qwertiy когда вопросов много, появляются страницы. Но при этом же не требуется пролистать все страницы чтобы добавить свой ответ. Ну и Вы не учитываете совсем вариант редактирования сообщения.

Comment: @alexolut, а было бы неплохо требовать, тут умудряются дубли писать когда всего два ответа, со страницами это 100% было бы, но у нас я еще ни разу не видел чтобы к одному вопросу было столько ответов, что появились бы страницы

Comment: @Grundy может меня неправильно поняли. Я не за расположение блока для ответа сразу под вопросом. А за возможность переместить его после начала редактирования туда куда хочется.

Comment: @alexolut, мне кажется затраты на реализацию будут большие и статус-отклонено

Comment: @Grundy наше дело - предложить :)

Comment: Я бы предложил динамический `topbar` (в вопросах там будет ссылка на создание ответа, например). Но отклонят это.

Comment: @alexolut, я отвечал VladD'у на его предложение разместить блок ответа сразу под вопросом. К вопросу это не относится. Что касается пролистывания страниц, то вряд ли захочется писать ответ, который уже есть где-то на 10й странице :)

Comment: Не, моё предложение в том, чтобы (1) кнопка «ответить» была в конце, как и сейчас, но (2) при этом область редактирования открывалась прямо под вопросом (и происходила автопрокрутка туда).

Comment: На самом деле все просто и сложно. Даже если тут люди будут за, то реализовывать это возьмутся не раньше 2567 года, ибо приоритеты совсем другие у разрабов. Намного проще сделать так: создать тему и опросить пользователей о плюшках, какие хотели бы видеть относительно UI. А далее сделать расширения для браузеров по этим пунктам списка. Типа как чувак [вот этот](http://stackapps.com/questions/6455/stack-exchange-notifications-inbox-achievements-score-improve-text-editor-an) ..... А разрабатывать, если угодно, можно одному, а можно с теми кто ЗА. опенсурсе.

Comment: @АлексейШиманский построить свой SO с блекджеком и ... системой плагинов.

Comment: @alexolut так точно. это смешно, но либо так либо никак в ближайшем бущем

Comment: @Qwertiy и сейчас плодятся дубли ответов.

Comment: @Qwertiy например, вчера дали сразу два коротких ответа, не содержащих ничего нового, на вопрос [Отличия абстрактного класса от интерфейса (abstract class and interface)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/235352/181472)

Answer (score 1):

С предпросмотром и прочими возможностями при написании ответа, например изменение высоты формы редактора и т.п, это будет не очень удобно. В качестве обходного решения можно открывать этот же вопрос в дополнительной вкладке, тем самым избавив себя от карусели перелистывания страниц при использовании прокрутки.

Размещение же кнопки ответа и/или редактора для написания ответов под самим вопросом, столкнётся с теми же трудностями, так как сами вопросы порой могут быть очень длинными и тоже требовать прокрутки.

Comment: Что за изменение размера формы редактора?

Comment: @alexolut высоты.

Answer (score -4):

На клавиатуре есть кнопки <kbd>Home</kbd> и <kbd>End</kbd>.

Comment: На некоторых нет, например на мобильных устройствах. А там где есть, нужно сначала вынести фокус из блока ввода. Да и `End` мотает в этом случае слишком низко из-за подвала большого размера.

Comment: @alexolut - Подвал можно убрать Адблоком (я на некоторых сайтах так делаю, плюс хедеры, боковые меню и т. п.) Но, конечно, это уже экстрим.